# Springboot & Mysql : cannot find table with uppercase names

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Under MySQL , I have those  tables in my database:

**store_commercialRange**  and **Store**

Uder my springboot app , I'm calling all my tables with lowercase names , so i'm calling it like this  :

**store_commercialrange** and **store**

Under my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`  , i ve set this :

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

I've noticed that the call of tables starting with Uppercase letters like **Store** ve passed with **store**  , but other tables ***which includes uppercase letters in the middle*** , do not pass.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDatabase.store_commercialrange' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementProxy.java:52) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

Comment: show spring-boot configuration for Mysql and sample entity class (`@Entity` annotated)

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by :

1. reverting back the initial config of `my.cnf`
2. dropping my database
3. stoping mysql server
4. add this again to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

   **[mysqld]**

   **lower_case_table_names = 1**
5. restart mysql service